# Declare an Async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in `React` and I'm trying to call an `async function`, but I get the `Unexpected reserved word 'await'.` ERROR

So my async function is in a `Helper class` who is supposed to do all the API call, and I'm calling this `Helper class` in my `Game function`

Here is my code from `Class Helper` :

```
class Helper {
      constructor() {
        this.state = {
          movieAnswer: {},
          profile_path:"",
          poster_path:"",
          myInit: { method: "GET", mode: "cors" }
        }
      }
  fetchMovieFunction = async (randomMovie) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
    fetch(`${MOVIE_KEY}${randomMovie}?api_key=${API_KEY}`, this.myInit)
    .then(error => resolve({ error }))
    .then(response => resolve({ poster_path: response.poster_path }));
    }); 
  }
```

and here is where I call `fetchMovieFunction` in my `game function` :

```
const helper = new Helper();


    function Game() {
     useEffect(() => {
        setRandomMovie(Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 - 1) + 1));
        const { poster_path, error } = await helper.fetchMovieFunction(randomMovie)
        if (error)
          return console.log({error});
        setApiMovieResponse({poster_path})
      }, [page]);
   return ();
    }
```

And I don't understand why on this line `const { poster_path, error } = await helper.fetchMovieFunction(randomMovie)` I get the `Unexpected reserved word 'await'.` Error like my function is not declare as an async function

Comment: The function in which the `await` keyword appears is **not** `async`. It's the arrow function `useEffect(() => {` in which you use `await`. Why do you assume that you have an `async` function there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two issues:

1. You should use await inside an async function
2. But the callback passed to `useEffect` should not be async. So, you can create an IIFE and make it async:

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        setRandomMovie(Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 - 1) + 1));
        const { poster_path, error } = await helper.fetchMovieFunction(randomMovie);
        if (error) return console.log({ error });
        setApiMovieResponse({ poster_path });
      })();
    }, [page]);
   ```

The callback itself shouldn't be async because that would make the callback return a promise and React expects a non-async function that is typically used to do some cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

You will necessarily need to wrap the hook callback logic into an `async` function and invoke it. React hook callbacks cannot be asynchronous, but they *can* call asynchronous functions.

Also, since React state updates are asynchronously processed, you can't set the `randomMovie` value and expect to use it on the next line in the same callback scope. Split this out into a separate `useEffect` to set the `randomMovie` state when the `page` dependency updates, and use the `randomMovie` as the dependency for the main effect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setRandomMovie(Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 - 1) + 1));
}, [page]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getMovies = async () => { // <-- declare async
    const { poster_path, error } = await helper.fetchMovieFunction(randomMovie);
    if (error) {
      console.log({error});
    } else {
      setApiMovieResponse({poster_path});
    }
  };

  if (randomMovie) {
    getMovies(); // <-- invoke
  }
}, [randomMovie]);
```

### FYI

`fetch` already returns a Promise, so wrapping it in a Promise is superfluous. Since you are returning the Promise chain there is also nothing to await. You can return the `fetch` (*and Promise chain*).

```
fetchMovieFunction = (randomMovie) => {
  return fetch(`${MOVIE_KEY}${randomMovie}?api_key=${API_KEY}`, this.myInit)
  .then(response => return {
    poster_path: response.poster_path
  })
  .catch(error => return { error });
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do so, It's not suggested to `asynchronize` a function as a callback function being used in `useEffect()` since Effect callbacks **are synchronous to prevent race conditions.**

the better approach would be **inside the useEffect callback**

check this out:

```
useEffect(() => {
     async function [name] () {
              .....
              .....
        }
     [name]();

},string[])
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetchMovieFunction` doesn't need to be `async` because you're *already* returning a promise. Instead just return the `fetch` (also a promise), [and catch any errors from that call in *that* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch):

```
fetchMovieFunction = (randomMovie) => {
  try {
    return fetch(`${MOVIE_KEY}${randomMovie}?api_key=${API_KEY}`, this.myInit)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

But your `useEffect`, [or rather the function you should be calling *within* the `useEffect`](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data), *does* need to be async (because you're using [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await), but now you can just pick up the data from the fetch when it resolves.

```
useEffect(() => {

  async function getData() {
    setRandomMovie(Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 - 1) + 1));
    const { poster_path } = await helper.fetchMovieFunction(randomMovie);
    setApiMovieResponse({ poster_path });
  }

  getData();

}, [page]);
```